# Regex exclude exact digit from digits

Tags: regex

Hello my fellow dream builders.

I am parsing time from twitter and I am using this regex:

```
    {

        match = /^[1]/.exec(obj.tweetTime);
        if(match != null){
            time = "1 hour ago";
        }
        else
        {
        match = /^[0-9]{1,2}/.exec(obj.tweetTime);
        time = match + " hours ago";
        }
    }
```

My question is, if there is simpler way to do this? As you can see, I have 2 digits for time. I just want to format my print right. Hour/Hours as you can see.

Is it possible to write only 1 regex and use only 1 conditional bracket?

PS: I am beginner at regex, and I know /^[0-9]{1,2}/ allow numbers from 0 to 99 practically, but as I said it works for my needs, just asking if it is possible to do this properly, since I lack knowledge.

Thank you, much love <3

Comment: Your first regex would also match if the hour is 10, 11 or 12 since all of these start with `1`. Are you sure you want to be using regex for this?

Comment: What should I use if not regex?

PS: I removed "^" so it doesn't watch whole line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
var match = obj.tweetTime.match(/^\d+$/);

if (match) {
  var time = match[0] + ' hour' + (match[0] == 1 ? '' : 's') + ' ago';
}
```

---

**EDIT** Turns out the string is formatted! In which case:

```
var match = obj.tweetTime.match(/^(\d+)([smhd])$/);

if (match) {
  var units = { s: 'second', m: 'minute', h: 'hour', d: 'day' },
      time  = match[1] + ' ' + units[match[2]] + (match[1] == 1 ? '' : 's') + ' ago';
}
```

To explain the regex:

```
^         Anchor matches to the beginning of the string
(\d+)     Capture one or more digits in first group
([smhd])  Capture s, m, h or d in second group
$         Anchor to end of string
```

Comment: string I receive from twitter is like this "13h" .. it adds h at end.

I like your idea, can you be kind and explain your regex? thy

Comment: Is that always the case? On my Twitter client, I see `13m` and `3d` in the same location - is that the same field? Anyway, my edit will work for the use case you mentioned.

Comment: I get 13h, 13m, 13s .. If it is more than 1 day it writes like "24 Jan"..

I only care for h,m and s.

I used this to filter some stuff: /[0-9]{1,2}[m,h,s]/ and than I use /[0-9]{1,2}[m]/ and [h] and [s] to get 1 level deeper, than I try to see if number is 1 or higher than 1 to properly print "hours ago" or "hour ago".

Comment: I didn't realise that the string was formatted in any fancy way. In which case, see edit!

Comment: Thanks so much you gave a lot effort into this, would vote up, but don't have enough reputation =/ Thank you both, you are good men!